# Force Refresh of Access Token in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Using [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js), how can I **force** `acquireTokenSilent()` to refresh the access token?

I can't seem to find [any methods](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/dev/docs/classes/_useragentapplication_.msal.useragentapplication.html) that I can call to clear the cache or remove a user from the cache.

---

**Background**

I need to refresh the access token b/c the claims have been changed for the user and I need the new values.  I don't want to wait for the token to expire before getting the new claims.

Comment: I was thinking about this some more; maybe I need updated id_token not an access_token.  Where are the claims?  In which token?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue .Did you got the solution ?

Comment: @NitishaSharma - I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/98/commits/767f9c5604950768ea06a5fa8fcb3e8056275dac) but they didn't seem to care/respond so I gave up and closed it.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Also looking to do the same as same scenario as you.

Comment: been too long, sorry, forgot what workaround I came up but if it comes back to me I'll be sure to share it, sorry.  @sharpc

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:
1. Hit F12, Go to Application, open storage( Local/Session) whatever you are using. You will find keys which are JSON objects with properties such as authority, clientID, scopes and userIdentifier. The object whose scope is set to clientId is your idtoken and all other objects which have "scopes" set to the scopes requested for the user correspond to access tokens. Delete all such objects which are access tokens and it will force the library to renew the token.

Comment: Thanks Rohit but I need a programmatic way.  I think I can take your idea come up with something though.  Thanks!